# Generate MD5 and retain "Accessed" time

Tags: c#, .net, md5

We are using the standard .NET 4 methods to generate MD5, however when we do, the "Accessed" field within Windows is changing.

Anyone aware of a solution to generate an MD5 without changing the "Accessed" or "Last Accessed" attribute?

Comment: Fetch it, compute the MD5 hash, then reset it to the value you fetched? Of course, that way you can't detect if someone else accessed it while you were computing the hash...

Comment: Not as graceful of a solution as I was hoping for...

Comment: Well fundamentally you *are* accessing the file. If arbitrary processes could say "I'm not really accessing the file, honest" then it wouldn't be a terribly useful property. (It's not clear to me that it's particularly useful in reality anyway, to be honest...)